# Have an HTML link always prompt Complete Action With on Android

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, onchange

I have looked around and cannot find anything helpful.

I have a web app I've been working on that lets you play video files, mainly mp4.  Depending on the mobile browser, when clicking the link, it will open in a new tab and play using HTML5 (Firefox does this), download it (Chrome does this sometimes), or ask what to do (Internet does this all the time, Chrome sometimes).

Can I force the Complete Action With dialog to come up when the link is clicked?

On top of this, I'm using drop-downs for linking because it looks neater.  The values are pulled for the options using PHP, so I have the option of detecting the browser through that if necessary.  I don't like JavaScript, but I'll use it if I have to.

My code in PHP:

```
<select width="100%" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option selected disabled>Choose Video Quality</option>
<?php
    foreach($show[additionalMedia] as $addt){
?>
    <option value="<?=$addt[url] ?>"><?=$addt[role] ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

My code as rendered HTML:

```
<select width="100%" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option selected disabled>Choose Video Quality</option>
    <option value="http://blip.tv/file/get/NostalgiaCritic-AdventureTimeVlogsMortalRecoil577.mp4">Source</option>
    <option value="http://blip.tv/file/get/NostalgiaCritic-AdventureTimeVlogsMortalRecoil150.m4v">Blip SD</option>
    <option value="http://blip.tv/file/get/NostalgiaCritic-AdventureTimeVlogsMortalRecoil599.mp4">Blip LD</option>
    <option value="http://blip.tv/file/get/NostalgiaCritic-AdventureTimeVlogsMortalRecoil515.m4v">Blip HD 720</option>
    <option value="http://blip.tv/file/get/NostalgiaCritic-AdventureTimeVlogsMortalRecoil642.m3u8">Blip HLS</option>
</select>
```

I won't post the `json_decode`d array that the data came from, but suffice it to say that `$addt[url]` is the video URL and that `$addt[role]` is the URL description.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting my old questions with some Android experience under my belt, I'm not sure this is possible.  The action chooser uses MIME-type to determine what application to use, and will display all Android applications that can handle that type.  The chooser won't display if the user has set a preference.

Hypothetically, the PHP could provide functionality to download the file with various MIME-types, "lying" to the Android device, to expand the number of available Open With options, but as it stands, Android will do the best it can to open whatever file is thrown at it.

Hack-y solution using false MIME types:

```
<select width="100%" onchange="location = '/download.php?mime=' + document.getElementById("mimetype").value + '&file=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
```